# Operator Instanceof gives different results in Console.log Concatenation

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, instanceof, console.log

Well, For debugging, I use `console.log` often & it Outputs a message to the Web Console. But I don't know why I'm getting a different result with `instanceof` operator with concatenation.

```
 console.log("Hello "+"Code!!"); //Prints `Hello Code!!` - Correct
 console.log("Hello ","Code!!"); //Prints `Hello Code!!` - Correct
 console.log("Hello "+"Code!! : "+Math.PI); //Prints `Hello Code!! : 3.141592653589793` - Correct
 console.log("Result ",[] instanceof Array); //Prints `Result true` - Correct
```

But the below line gives output as `false`. Why it isn't `Result true`?

```
console.log("Result "+[] instanceof Array); //Prints `false` Why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the two instances...

`console.log("Result "+([] instanceof Array)); // Result true`

Because this is not an Array --> `"Result "+[]`

When you use the comma, you separate the two, that is why it works.
When you use +, it combines the two into a string, then checks if it is an Array

Comment: Oh My Bad!! Thanks @Whitehat..Cheers..:)

Answer (score 1):

Because this code:

```
console.log("Result "+[] instanceof Array); //Prints `false` Why?
```

Actually "adds" a `String` ("Result ") to an `Array` ([]), which equals to a String. See this example:

```
console.log(typeof("simple string"+[])); // Will print "string"
```

and String, is definitely not an `instanceof` Array :-)

Comment: Thanks @Ronen..:) Cheers!!